# Execute Command (cmd) by Hyperlink or Javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cmd

I am looking for a way to make the client machine execute some command line in the command prompt (cmd) from a web page (intranet application).

I guess (and hope) this cannot be done by browser standards. But **assuming I have full access to the clients' machines and can setup everything I need on them** - Is there a way to make `Internet Explorer` trigger a launch of `cmd` and execute a given command? So I could then include hyperlinks or javascript to access it like, for example, this:

```
<a href="cmd:C\Program Files\...">Click Me</a>

executeCmd('C:\\Program Files\\...');
```

If there is no easy way to configure something like this, I'd be very thankful for workarounds or different approaches to trigger a command from a web page.

Comment: I'm not certain if this is _exactly_ what you're after, but it's a step in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15351508/using-a-wscript-shell-activex-to-execute-a-command-line

Comment: Use a custom protocol handler. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the microsoft documentation

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using

```
<a href="cmd:C\Program Files\...">Click Me</a>

executeCmd('C:\\Program Files\\...');
```

Use this

```
<a href="file:\\C:\Program Files\...">Click Me</a>
```